# Get the file name of single HTML file in a directory

Tags: windows, firefox, cmd

Imagine a directory in Windows which has only one single `.html` file (or any other extension). I.e., when I do `dir *.html` only one file is listed.

Is there any simple command to obtain that file name without going into a `for` loop, which uses `set`? I'm running a command line from another software and it doesn't have access to create files (using the `>`) nor to the environment variables (using `set`).

In this particular case, I'd like to open such file with Firefox command line

```
C:\mydir>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" [single_file].html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DOS is horrendous**

If you really want a one liner...

`dir /b *.html > tmp & set /p var=<tmp & del tmp & "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" %var%`

I have Chrome, so just substitute your path to Firefox for it. `dir /b *.html` is the key here. It lists the file only, with none of the other headers that `dir` usually puts. the `/b` is for BARE.

Edit: Since you don't have access to writing files and setting variables, I don't think you have an option besides using a `for` loop. This one here is pretty short

```
for %h in (*.html) do start Chrome %h
```

You should check that you can start Firefox by running `start Firefox`. Else you'll have to substitute the path in like so:

```
for %h in (*.html) do "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" %h
```

If Firefox is your default browser, you can just run:

```
for %h in (*.html) do %h
```

Comment: Interesting! Is there any solution without `set`, using the environment variables?

Comment: Is there anything simpler, without `set`? Yes, I agree, dos is horrendous.

Comment: This envolves creating files (`>`) and dealing the environment variables (`set`) and I have access to neither.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll look into it some more and see if I can find anything.

Comment: Quick question: Is Firefox not your default browser?

Comment: No, Firefox is not the default browser.